# Expiration date on a user in a specific database

Tags: sql-server, security, users

Some of our developers needs access to some of the databases in production for a short period. Is there a way for me to set an expiration date on a user in a specific database?
Just to clarify I do not want the login to expire, just the user in a specific database.

```
USE [Database1] 
CREATE USER [Developer1] FOR LOGIN [Developer1] WITH expirydate = '2018.01.01'
--Add some roles
GO
USE [Database2]
CREATE USER [Developer1] FOR LOGIN [Developer1] WITH expirydate = '2018.02.02'
--Add some roles
```

*MSSQL 2014, 2016 & 2017*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to set an expiration date on a database user.

I believe the best solution would be what [Edgar Allan Bayron](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/108119/edgar-allan-bayron) suggested:

> you can set a sql server agent job to run daily which compares with today's date. If that date is equal to the "expiry date", then execute a query where it will disable the specific user

Here's a slightly more fleshed out version of that idea:

- Create a new database for administrative use (if you don't already have one). We'll assume it's called `dba_utilities`.
- In the `dba_utilities` database, create a table named `db_user_expiration`, with columns `database` (`nvarchar(128)`), `username` (`nvarchar(128)`), and `expiration_date` (`datetime`) (plus an `id`, `integer`, `IDENTITY`). You may want to have a `removed` `bit` or `char(1)` column as well.
- In the same database, create a procedure to:

  - identify rows from the table where the user account has expired;
  - for each row, create a dynamic SQL statement to `DROP` the user from the indicated database
  - If the drop is successful, remove the row from the table (or, mark the row as `removed`).

  If there will only be a few of these at a time, I'd simply use a `STATIC LOCAL` cursor to loop through the records; if the numbers will be very large, you could generate a single SQL statement to do all the accounts at once, but that's more complicated.

  NOTE: If you don't create your users with a default schema, then they'll wind up having a schema with the same name as the user created for them. The schema must either be dropped or moved to a different owner before the user can be dropped. Unless your users need a schema of their own, I'd assign them to a default schema owned by the database owner ([dbo] may work well, in most cases), so this is not a problem.
- Run this procedure from a SQL Server job as often as you like (from once a day to once an hour, if appropriate). The `expiration_date` column I suggest is a `datetime`, so you can specify the time of day when the expiration should take effect, and the next run after that time should see the user dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply @RDFozz. I was afraid there was no easy, out of the box, solution to this problem :/

Your solution would work, but I’ll probably going to do something like this:

```
USE [Database1] 
CREATE USER [ToDate_20180101@Developer1] FOR LOGIN [Developer1] 
--Add some roles
GO
USE [Database2]
CREATE USER [ToDate_20180202@Developer1] FOR LOGIN [Developer1]
 --Add some roles
```

And create a job that runs every night to deletes users with names that have “expired” and all users missing the “todate” prefix.

Comment: That could work as well!